# Как удалить строку в таблице через checkbox php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу правильно написать код удаления для строки в таблице через `checkbox`.
Алгоритм такой: выбираю `checkbox` в строке, затем нажимаю на кнопку "удалить" и запись удаляется из таблицы.
Код для `checkbox` имеет следующий вид:
в строке

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="abs[]" value="<?=$items[$key]['id'] ?>"></td>
```

у меня создается массив `checkbox` под названием `abs`, в `value` я приписал код php, который определяет `id` строки, чтобы знать, какую строку нужно удалить.
Вот код который я написал, он не работает. Подскажите, как правильно нужно сделать чтобы строка в таблице удалялась.
У меня стоит следующая проверка: если есть массив `abs(checkbox)` и нажата кнопка `argys`, то выполняется условие.
У меня все сделано на PDO php, и я не понимаю, как изменить запрос под `checkbox`.

```
if(isset($_POST['argys']) and (isset($_POST['abs']))) 
{ 
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $result=$dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `Oke`.`tovars` WHERE `tovars`.`id` = :id;");
    $result->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $result->execute();
}
```

Comment: массив checkbox $_POST['abs'] я сохранил в сессии.

Comment: строка в таблице выглядит так <td><input type="checkbox" name="abs[]" value="<?=$items[$key]['id'] ?>"></td>

Comment: покажите пожалуйста, код JS  и HTML. еще убедитесь что у вас в массивах. print_r('<pre>');
print_r($_POST);
print_r('</pre>'); или var_dump('<pre>',$_POST,'</pre>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

делаешь невидимое поле `<input type="hidden" name = deletedID value= $id />` потом ставишь чекбокс `<input type="checkbox" name="abs" />`все.

```
<form action="delete.php" >


 <input type="hidden" name = deletedID value= $id />
   <input type="checkbox" name="abs" />
   <input type="submit"  />
</form>

if(isset($_POST['deletedID ']) and (isset($_POST['abs'])) and $_POST['abs']=='on')
```

{

```
$id=$_POST['deletedID '];
$result=$dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `Oke`.`tovars` WHERE `tovars`.`id` = :id;");
$result->bindParam(':id', $id);
$result->execute();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение моего вопроса, проверил работает идеально.

```
$bigimage = $_POST['checkbox'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM imagegallery WHERE id = :id");
                                                       //   ^ named placeholder
foreach ($bigimage as $id) {
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
                // ^ put an key value pair array inside with the 
                // designated named placeholder along with the value
}
```